# Fail to import Hadoop sandbox to Oracle virtual box

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, hortonworks-data-platform

My problem is when I tried to import the sandbox to virtual box, there was an error which said

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1.
>
> The virtual machine 'Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
>
> ```
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Component: Machine
> Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
> ```

I don't know what might be wrong here. My system is Windows 8.1 pro. Any ideas about how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be solved by installing the most recent virtual machine

Update: the version I am using is 4.3.15r95713 and the version that failed to import sandbox is 4.3.14 and in the description of 4.3.15 version, it says it has fixed some bugs about its incompatibility with antivirus software. Hope that helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Damien Joe: I don't understand your comment. This provides an answer to the problem.

Comment: can you add the version of the virtual machine that works and the version of virtual box you are using??